# magento 1.9,error when start cron.sh "no php in (/usr/bin:/bin)"

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-cron, cronjobs

I'm trying to run cron.sh file, to earn my crons, but i have problem.

I have this errors:

```
which: no php in (/usr/bin:/bin) /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 2: /bin: Is a directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 3: backup_1569226546: command not found /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 4: backup_1569226546: command not found /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 5: backup_1569226546: command not found /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 6: backup_1569226546: command not found /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 7: ` * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)'
```

I went to google and found the answers add `#!/usr/bin/php` on `cron.php` file
but it didn’t help me

i have this error

```
which: no php in (/usr/bin:/bin) /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.sh: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I went further to the Internet, but did not find the answer. Tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: check this out, at the end of the first error message: ```syntax error near unexpected token `(' /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/mysite.com/cron.php: line 7```